# Java Textio file addition

Tags: java

Where to put the textio.java and its classes. I am using jdk 12.0.1. it is the error cmd is showing on comipiling file that uses textio class.
Please tell me the correct directory where to put textio class file in jdk 12.0.1 folder.

Comment: Hi @Mohd Bilal, what have you tried? What error message are you seeing? I highly recommend reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive the best answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to add third party libraries to your runtime.  Without more information, the lowest energy way you're looking for isn't quite clear.

I believe the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is what you want.  If it's not defined, you may define one by whatever process matches your operating system.

CLASSPATH is one way for your machine to tell your java installation which folders jars and other jvm bytecode are located in so that your java runtime can load them when your program starts.  This can be anywhere, but depending on your operating system, there are standard locations that are often good to follow.

In linux/unix/OSX, you may run `echo $CLASSPATH`, and a non-empty result means that it's set.  If it doesn't exist, then you may run this command to create it pointing to the folder you choose.  `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jars`.  Just keep in mind that without some extra steps, this will be reset on next reboot.

If you're using an IDE such as eclipse or idea, then there are project-specific solutions that can be done as configuration options within your IDE, which will keep things you don't want globally available on your machine from being loaded up every time.